# Recovering Trello boards

Tags: trello

Is there a way to get a closed Trello board back from archive? It seems you can only read archived cards, not boards.

(A better warning for what "closing" a board will do might help, too. I accidentally closed my current project.

...Its obvious NOW, but it wasn't then)

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the boards button in the upper right
2. Click **`View Closed Boards`** (at the bottom)
3. Find the board you'd like to re-open, and click the <kbd>Re-open</kbd> button

[image: View Closed Boards]