# Trello re-open closed board in Android app

Tags: trello, trello-boards

How do I re-open a closed board in Trello??.

After a google search this is the first result [Recovering Trello boards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31852/recovering-trello-boards) but since then the application has changed and that answer is no longer valid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inexplicably this can only be done using the web application not the android app.

https://help.trello.com/article/781-reopening-a-closed-board